# How to sequentially execute click.command

Tags: python, click, command-line-arguments, python-click

I am trying to execute multiple `@click.command()` one after the other. None of the functions expect inputs from the other. The issue I'm seeing is that the main program executes only the first `click.command()` and exits.

I have tried grouping the `click.command()`s but it still does the same thing.

```
@click.command('make_and_init_model')    
@click.option('--use_all_gpu', default= "y", prompt='Use all available GPUs? y/n')
def make_and_init_model(use_all_gpu):
    debris_model = make_unet()
    if use_all_gpu == "y":
        print("Identifying available GPUs")
        gpus_to_use = [i for i in mx.test_utils.list_gpus()]
    else:
        gpus_to_use = [int(num) for num in input("Enter space separated GPU ids to use for training").split()]

    print("Using GPUs :",gpus_to_use)
    print("Initializing model")
    model.initialize(ctx = [mx.gpu(i) for i in gpus_to_use], force_reinit=True)
    print("Model initialized")
    return model



@click.command('load_dataset') 
@click.option('--base_dir', default = "./train", prompt ="Enter base path to training dataset")
@click.option('--use_default_dir_names', default="y", prompt= "Use default dataset directory names (img and gt)? y/n")
def load_dataset(base_dir, use_default_dir_names):
    try:
        base_dir_path = os.path.abspath(base_dir)
    except:
        print("Please check the base directory path entered. Exiting script...")
        sys.exit(1)

    if use_default_dir_names == "y":
        image_dir_name="img"
        gt_dir_name="gt"
        img_format = "rgb"
        ext=".tif"
    else:
        image_dir_name = input("Enter image directory name")
        gt_dir_name = input("Enter groundtruth directory name")
        img_format = input("Enter image format (ex: rgb, bgr etc)")
        ext = input("Enter full image extension (ex: .tif, .jpg etc)")
    train = DataSet.get_from_directory(base_dir = base_dir_path, 
                                    feature_dir = image_dir_name, 
                                    gt_dir = gt_dir_name, 
                                    image_format = img_format,
                                    termination=ext)
    print("Number of training images found :", len(train))
    return train



@click.command('weights_path_and_name')    
@click.option('--weights_path', default = "./weights", prompt = "Enter path to where the weights are to be saved")
@click.option('--experiment_name', default = "training_1", prompt = "Enter experiment name")
def weights_path_and_name(weights_path, experiment_name):
    try:
        save_weights_path = os.path.abspath(weights_path)
        if not os.path.exists(save_weights_path):
            os.makedirs(save_weights_path)
    except:
        print('Please check the save weights path entered. Exiting script')
        sys.exit(1)
    return save_weights_path, experiment_name


if __name__ == "__main__":
    model = make_and_init_model()
    train = load_dataset()
    save_weights_path, experiment_name = weights_path_and_name()
```

But it only runs `make_and_init_model` and then exits. Each of the individual function is correct in itself, but I am unable to run them sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older question, but this is actually a valid use case for click. Here's a minimum example from their website, where they [chain commands together](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/commands/#multi-command-chaining).

```py
@click.group(chain=True)
def cli():
    pass


@cli.command('sdist')
def sdist():
    click.echo('sdist called')


@cli.command('bdist_wheel')
def bdist_wheel():
    click.echo('bdist_wheel called')
```

And here is the invocation from the command line and output:

```sh
$ setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
sdist called
bdist_wheel called
```

For your actual question, you could add a group and nest the commands under it, as such:

```py
@click.group(chain=True)
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command('make_and_init_model')
@click.option('--use_all_gpu', default= "y", prompt='Use all available GPUs? y/n')
def make_and_init_model(use_all_gpu):
    debris_model = make_unet()
    if use_all_gpu == "y":
        print("Identifying available GPUs")
        gpus_to_use = [i for i in mx.test_utils.list_gpus()]
    else:
        gpus_to_use = [int(num) for num in input("Enter space separated GPU ids to use for training").split()]

    print("Using GPUs :",gpus_to_use)
    print("Initializing model")
    model.initialize(ctx = [mx.gpu(i) for i in gpus_to_use], force_reinit=True)
    print("Model initialized")
    return model



@cli.command('load_dataset')
@click.option('--base_dir', default = "./train", prompt ="Enter base path to training dataset")
@click.option('--use_default_dir_names', default="y", prompt= "Use default dataset directory names (img and gt)? y/n")
def load_dataset(base_dir, use_default_dir_names):
    try:
        base_dir_path = os.path.abspath(base_dir)
    except:
        print("Please check the base directory path entered. Exiting script...")
        sys.exit(1)

    if use_default_dir_names == "y":
        image_dir_name="img"
        gt_dir_name="gt"
        img_format = "rgb"
        ext=".tif"
    else:
        image_dir_name = input("Enter image directory name")
        gt_dir_name = input("Enter groundtruth directory name")
        img_format = input("Enter image format (ex: rgb, bgr etc)")
        ext = input("Enter full image extension (ex: .tif, .jpg etc)")
    train = DataSet.get_from_directory(base_dir = base_dir_path,
                                       feature_dir = image_dir_name,
                                       gt_dir = gt_dir_name,
                                       image_format = img_format,
                                       termination=ext)
    print("Number of training images found :", len(train))
    return train



@cli.command('weights_path_and_name')
@click.option('--weights_path', default = "./weights", prompt = "Enter path to where the weights are to be saved")
@click.option('--experiment_name', default = "training_1", prompt = "Enter experiment name")
def weights_path_and_name(weights_path, experiment_name):
    try:
        save_weights_path = os.path.abspath(weights_path)
        if not os.path.exists(save_weights_path):
            os.makedirs(save_weights_path)
    except:
        print('Please check the save weights path entered. Exiting script')
        sys.exit(1)
    return save_weights_path, experiment_name


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

Then you can invoke your application in the following way:

```sh
my_application make_and_init_model load_dataset weights_path_and_name
```

Answer (score -3):

`click.command` is not designed to be run sequentially. Although it's possible to [invoke other commands](http://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/advanced/#invoking-other-commands) in a command, that does not trigger *prompt* option. I believe explicitly specifying options is the design choice made by `click`.

In your usage case, I would suggest split the API (function call) and CLI (command line interface), via the following minimum example.

```py
# t.py
import click
from click.testing import CliRunner


def func1(a):
    print(f'Run func1 with a = {a}')


def func2(b):
    print(f'Run func2 with b = {b}')


@click.group()
def cli():
    pass


@cli.command()
@click.option('--a', prompt='a?')
def cmd1(a):
    func1(a)


@cli.command()
@click.option('--b', prompt='b?')
def cmd2(b):
    func2(b)


@cli.command()
@click.option('--a', prompt='a?')
@click.option('--b', prompt='b?')
def cmd_all(a, b):
    func1(a)
    func2(b)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

Then you can do

```
$ python t.py cmd1
a?: 5
Run func1 with a = 5
$ python t.py cmd2
b?: 10
Run func2 with b = 10
$ python t.py cmd-all
a?: 5
b?: 10
Run func1 with a = 5
Run func2 with b = 10
```

Alternative, sharing the options signatures is possible,

```
# t.py
import click
from click.testing import CliRunner


def func1(a):
    print(f'Run func1 with a = {a}')


def func2(b):
    print(f'Run func2 with b = {b}')


@click.group()
def cli():
    pass


opta = click.option('--a', prompt='a?')
optb = click.option('--b', prompt='b?')


@cli.command()
@opta
def cmd1(a):
    func1(a)


@cli.command()
@optb
def cmd2(b):
    func2(b)


@cli.command()
@opta
@optb
def cmd_all(a, b):
    func1(a)
    func2(b)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

---

> Edit: This is the first time I am asking a question on here. Please bear with me for any rookie mistakes with tags etc

That's fine. Please try to make a minimum example when asking questions next time.